# Microsoft Graph API - Is it possible send chat message using client credentials flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been trying send a chat message to individual user in application mode, I mean, without each user being required to authenticate and grant access to the application. The idea is to make it transparent to them.

So I send this request to get access token:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type=client_credentials,
client_id={app id registered in azure portal},
client_secret={registered app key},
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

Sending this request, I got the token.

Using this token, I try to send a message to the user using this request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{chat-id}/messages
```

With this payload in JSON:

```
{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

The problem is that I got this error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-05-18T17:49:24",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

An interesting point is that I can create a Chat, using the same logic explained.
I send this request with the token that I got:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats
```

Payload in Json:

```
{
  "chatType": "oneOnOne",
  "members": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('user1')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('user2')"
    }
  ]
}
```

To create Chat it works fine, but to send a message, I got an error.

I have all application permissions.

Comment: Sending chat message using `Application` permissions is **not supported**. Check this  [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions-for-chat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to this [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions-for-chat), sending chat message using Application permissions is **not supported**.  As client credentials flow works with only **Application** permissions, it's not possible to send chat message using that flow.

But for **creating chat** via Microsoft Graph API, Application permissions are supported. Check this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used above token to create chat with this query, I got **response** successfully like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "chatType": "oneOnOne",
  "members": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('user1')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('user2')"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

But, I got **same error** when I tried to send message in this chat using same token like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{chat-id}/messages
{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you need to grant **Delegated** permissions to the application and generate access token using Delegated flows like authorization code flow or username password flow etc...

I added **`ChatMessage.Send`** Delegated permission in my application like below:

[image]

In my case, I generated **access token** with username password flow where user interaction is not required like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:password
client_id: <appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
username: username@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token in below query to send message in chat, I got **response** successfully like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{chat-id}/messages
{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I have no words to thank you, Sridevi. It works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for this, but doesnt work with MFA. Is there any way to get this working with MFA? I've tried to use the delegate option (through a webapp), still it doesnt work

Comment: @S.Krishna Note that, username password flow won't work with MFA. You need to switch to delegated flows like authorization code flow or interactive flow for generating access token.

Comment: @Sridevi Sorry to barge, my requirement is similar but little different. We are creating a bot to send message to a teams chatgroup on certain events. We can create an azure ad application with permissions to chatsend but security want to ensure that the app permission is limited to only to the chat group id .. Any suggesstion

Comment: @Sridevi In the step where you created the chat, using your application, is that a chat between two Teams users or the app and a Teams user (if latter do you then use the app's client ID)? 

I am trying to create a notification app, but to be able to send 1:1 messages to a user I first need a chatID for the user and the app.